# Re-fetch backbone collection on create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a list of "entries" to manage. The list is displayed in the lower part of the screen while the entry form displays at the top of the page.
Each entry holds a "entryDate" property.

The list is bound to a select "month" period (e.g. August 2014), it shows only entries between the selected date range. The entries are paginated, too. I show X entries per page, with infinite scrolling. The list's sort order is descending on entryDate, most recent entries are shown first.

If entryDate was always the currentDate, I could prepend the new row to the list, without re-rendering the whole thing, but that's not the case. I think it's overkill to check whether the entered date is included in the selected period or it isn't, just to know if I have to reload the list.

Now, I wanna make it easy by just fetching/resetting the list on every successfully insertion. But... I can't do it.

A snippet from my view code:

```
initialize: function() {

        this.collection = new EntriesCollection();
        this.fetchTransactions();
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.fetchTransactions );

        this.rowViews = [];
        this.render();
    },

fetchTransactions: function() {
        this.collection.fetch({ reset:true });
    },

addEntry: function() { // on form submit

        var entryData = {};
// load data from form...
        this.collection.create( entryData );
    },
```

This does not work properly, the list is not re-fetched.

Is the 'add' collection event supposed to trigger before or after the fetch?

Comment: Can you add the code where you add the new model to the collection?

Comment: it is just this.collection.create( entryData );

Comment: maybe you can use {wait:true} in your create

Comment: @LaurensKling that did the trick! Thank you! I just read about that option in the official doc. However, can you suggest me some reading/examples about it, too?

Comment: i've added an awnser, it would be nice if you could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `Wait` option.

This is described well at http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save and http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create

giving your `create` the `{wait:true}` option will make sure the `add` will only be triggered when the `create` is succesfully accepted by the server. The normal behavior is that the model is added to the collection and after it will be sent to the server. The wait command changes this around.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful bit when figuring out events/when they fire is to just log them all out.

So you can do something like

```
events: {
  "all": "log"
}

log: function(e) {
  console.log e;
}
```

And you'll be able to see each event/when it's fire. I find it super useful when trying to figure out which event to attach to/what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
```

with

```
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'sync', this.render );
```